# Fast way of relabeling array elements or making elements contiguous in python

Tags: arrays, numpy, image-processing, scipy, numba

I have a massive size 3d array to deal with. I want to relabel elements in following way

```
import numpy as np
given_array = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 23, 23, 23])
required_array = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

I know there is `relabel_sequential` method in `skimage.segmentation` but its slow for my purpose. Any idea to do this in fast way will be appreciated.

Comment: Are those elements always sorted?

Comment: No they are not but `given_array.sort()` can be used.@Divaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the given array is unsorted, this will be quicker than sorting it:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit()
def relabel_fast(array, count):
    i = 0
    while i < len(array):
        data = array[i]
        count[data] += 1
        i += 1
    a = 1 # Position in count
    b = 0 # Position in array
    c = 0 # The current output number
    while a < len(count):
        d = 0 # The number of 'c' to output
        if count[a] > 0:
            while d < count[a]:
                array[b] = c
                b += 1
                d += 1
            c += 1
        a += 1

def relabel(given_array):
    # Arrays cannot be created within Numba, so create the count array before calling the Numba function
    count = np.zeros(np.max(given_array) + 1, dtype=int)
    relabel_fast(given_array, count)


#given_array = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 23, 23, 23])
given_array = np.array([1, 23, 1, 3, 8, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 5, 8, 23, 23, 1])
relabel(given_array)

given_array
```

#### Output

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: This code is `5x faster` than `relabel_sequential` for  `np.random.random_integers(1, 50000, 1000000000)`. Thanks for this @Thane Brooker I am accepting this answer. Why do you not prefer to return in numba function. Am i missing something? @Thane Brooker

Comment: @ZAK The function overwrites the provided array rather than creating a new array.  By not returning an array, it makes this point obvious and there can be no confusion.  If the function returned an array, it would be ambiguous as to exactly what was being returned:- is it returning the original input array, or did it create a new array?  So it isn't anything to do with Numba, but rather making it easier for users of the code to understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way should be to write a specific numba function that is tailored to do what you want.

#### Example

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit()
def relabel(array):
    i = 0
    n = -1
    previous = 0
    while i < len(array):
        if previous != array[i]:
            previous  = array[i]
            n += 1
        array[i] = n
        i += 1

given_array = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 23, 23, 23])
relabel(given_array)

given_array
```

#### Output

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

This example makes a lot of assumptions about the input, i.e. the array is sorted, the first number is positive, it is a 1D shape, you want to overwrite the array.

Comment: The code seems to work fine when the array is sorted as you mentioned. For `a = np.random.random_integers(1, 50000, 100000000)`, `a.sort()` requires `7.06 s` and after sorting `relabel` takes only `0.25  s`. On the other hand `relabel_sequential` takes `7.5 s`. Do you have any solution to `sort()` array faster? @ Thane Brooker

Comment: @ZAK I would create a "counter" 1D Array with a length that matches the maximum integer size of the input array.  In your example, that would be 50000.  Next I would iterate through each integer of your array, and increase the cell of the counter array corresponding to the integer.  So if the first item of your array was 25, then cell 25 of counter would increase.  And so on.  At the end, I'd step through the counter array, and output the number counted into a new array.  This would only require one iteration of the input array and one iteration of the counter array.

Comment: @ZAK I created the above in a new answer, let me know how timings compare.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it is fast enough.  Use the `inverse` returned by `numpy.unique` with the argument `return_inverse=True`:

```
In [52]: given_array = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 23, 23, 23])             

In [53]: u, inv = np.unique(given_array, return_inverse=True)                                    

In [54]: inv                                                                                     
Out[54]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: for `np.arange(300*300*300).reshape(300,300,300)`, `np.unique` takes `1.74 s ± 15.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` while `relabel_sequential` takes `979 ms ± 9.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. I am dealing with `2000 x 2000x 2000` 3d arrays. @Warren Weckesser